# QGIS 3.10.3 line out of the route

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, filter, offset

I am using QGIS 3.10.3. I try to symbolize routes in both direction (CL1 and CR1). Using the rule based symbology and created 4 sections according to the values. I filtered the data using <= and >= symbols.
[image]
Example: Subsection <= 0.000000 AND Subsection >= 39.999999

Then, I changed the offset to -3 for the opposite road (CL1). For some reasons, some lines are missing in the network.  I have a feeling the offset must be the reason but not 100 percent sure.
[image]

Comment: offset shouldn't be a problem, did you check that offset (and whole symbology) unit are all mm ?

Comment: Sorry it's QGIS 3.10.3.A Coruna

Comment: yes they are in millimeters

Comment: Try reversing the line direction of the outlier

Comment: Thanks, I created a new shapefile for the missing line and reversed the offset to 3. It seems to work as the line is now in the network. I suppose I will have to make a new shapefile with all the missing ones and do the same thing.

Comment: The offset left or right is dependent on  line direction. You can reverse the direction of lines by selecting them and using the QGIS tool Processing > Toolbox > Vector geometry > Reverse line direction

Comment: Cheers Hans, it works for one segment.  Now I will need to find all the lines not connected to the network and do the same. I appreciate your help

Comment: Glad to help out, I have added my comment as answer

Answer (score 2):

The offset left or right is dependent on line direction. You can reverse the direction of lines by selecting them and using the QGIS tool Processing > Toolbox > Vector geometry > Reverse line direction